# how to remove an error in "import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody;"

Tags: android

I tried to download [httpmime-4.0.1.jar] but still the error is there and     -------------------------------

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask {
        @Override

```
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();





HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.WebServiceURL) + "/cfc/iphonewebservice.cfc?method=uploadPhoto");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(

         HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);





ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            entity.addPart("photoId", new StringBody(getIntent()



.getStringExtra("photoId")));
            entity.addPart("returnformat", new StringBody("json"));
            entity.addPart("uploaded", new ByteArrayBody(data,"myImage.jpg"));



    entity.addPart("photoCaption", new StringBody(caption.getText().toString()));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
   localContext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a libs folder in your application then add “httpmime-4.1.3.jar”, after that you need to show this directory to your project properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this JAR to build path. If you are using Eclipse just copy it to project folder. Then in Eclipse right mouse click on it, BUILD PATH->ADD TO BUILD PATH